# Using a phone Bluetooth headpiece to listen to music from computer

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, media, wireless-headset

I have a Bluetooth headset (Handsfree) [HipStreet BT Lite](http://www.hipstreetonline.com/products/Bluetooth-Headset-BT%252d102.html), this supports phone audio but does not support media streaming.  I downloaded an app for Android ([BTmono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bedoig.BTmono&hl=en)) that changed this behavior and allowed me to use it to listen to music with the headpiece. Is there any Windows software that will allow me to use my headpiece for listening to music?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has a bluetooth adapter, try pairing the headset with it and see if it shows up as an audio output device (Start -> Control Panel -> Sound).

Comment: No, It does not, As I have mentioned it has only "Phone Audio" as Output, It gives an option (the only option) to forward Skype Calls to it.